# Microsoft Azure - how to store backup data

Tags: azure, backup, azure-storage

I have a trivial and simple task - I want to store some my data (documents, photos etc) on Azure as backup. Which type of service should I select? Store as Blob? But I want to save a structure of data (folders, subfolders etc). Azure Backup? It stores only archive data, I don't want to archive it all in one. DocumentDB? I not need to have features like return json format etc... What is the best way to store many (thousands) files (big and small) to save folder structure without archivation to one file (so, I want to have a simple way to get only one file quickly)

I use Windows 7.

Comment: Please, take a look a this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx and this http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/. I've never used it but it's worth checking.

Comment: I'd suggest that you look at OneDrive which provides you with 15GB of free storage (new registrations) and provides a windows sync client that means your 'archived' files are always a click away and can be shared amongst multiple devices. https://onedrive.live.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what knightpfhor wrote above you might also want to take a look at [Getting Started with AzCopy](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/) - it is a Windows tool that helps you copy content to / from your local storage to Blob Storage. PowerShell and XPlatCLI are other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've described, blob storage can achieve what you're after.  While blob storage doesn't technically support folders, it does let you include `\` in the file names which are interpreted by some blob storage clients as folders (for example the free Cerebrata Azure Explorer).  So if you have

```
RootDrive
|
--My Pictures
    |
    Picture1.jpg
    Picture2.jpg
--My Other Picutres
    |
    Picture1.jpg
```

You could create blobs with the names:

RootDrive\My Pictures\Picture1.jpg

RootDrive\My Pictures\Picture2.jpg

RootDrive\My Other Picutres\Picture1.jpg

And they have the ability to be interpreted as folders.

Answer (score 0):

I examined Recovery Services deeply and it works now (from december 2014) for Windows client versions too (including Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1). It allows to backup selected files and folders.
This is a guide how to use it
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/04/back-up-your-data-to-the-cloud-with-3-simple-steps/